# What's the difference between these MD5 hashes?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking

What's the difference between this format:

```
Hash found: admin:$1$$oLN1UCc1Y3T30QkMcKMSx0
```

and the following:

```
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
```

And also,

How to turn the first hash format into the second one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt the first example is just a hash. It looks like it contains the user name in the clear and possibly other information. Where did you get it? It is not really possible to rehash without knowing the cleartext value.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering too. But I got that after running routersploit on my router using Kali Linux and the output says exactly that >> `Hash found: admin:$1$$oLN1UCc1Y3T30QkMcKMSx0`. I also found a similar case here [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pentesting/comments/e7u577/how_to_bruteforce_this_md5/)

Answer (score 2):

The first example looks like a *shadow file* format: **ID** (`admin`) **Algorithm** (`1` = MD5) **Salt** (none) **Hash** (`oLN1UCc1Y3T30QkMcKMSx0`), with the hash in what seems to be Base64 format.

The second (`5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`) appears to be a hex string of 128 bits consistent with being an MD5 hash as well.

However, converting both to binary & then back to their opposite formats, the two hashes do not match:

- Base64 of the binary value represented by the hex string (`5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`) is `X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ`.
- Conversely the hex string of the base64 hash (`oLN1UCc1Y3T30QkMcKMSx0`) is
  `a0b3755027356374f7d1090c70a312c7`.

  ```
         ------- Edit -----
  ```

As ***user1686*** pointed out: *oLN1UCc1Y3T30QkMcKMSx0* is MD5crypt, which is a thousand rounds of MD5 with extras at each round. **If** both of these hashes are in fact from the same password, it should be possible to convert the straight MD5 hash to its equivalent no-salt MD5Crypt by bypassing the first MD5 calculation in the MD5Crypt and feeding it the hash instead of the password.

Answer (score 2):

The part after the last $ is base64-encoded, which is a reasonably compact (four characters becomes three bytes) way to represent binary data as common, printable characters (not ASCII control codes or anything requiring the high bit). The second hash is simply hex-encoded, which is less efficient (four characters becomes two bytes) but easier to read, especially for programmers (who use hex all the time).

EDIT: Additionally, the first algorithm is almost certainly md5*crypt*, which is an iterated MD5 with some additional stuff done. Thus, it's not going to produce the same output as base MD5 for a given input. And indeed we see that it does not: if you convert the part after then last $ to hex, comes out a0b3755027356374f7d1090c70a312c7. That also might (at least in part) be because I think md5crypt uses a custom base64, which has the same characters as normal base64 in a different order.

The first hash is an example of the /etc/shadow password format. The `$1` means MD5crypt, and the lack of anything between the next two $ characters means that it's unsalted. We have no such info for the second; it could be salted, or possibly a different password, different hash algorithm, or both. It's likelier to be bare MD5 than md5crypt, though.

*Edited to reflect the difference between MD5 and md5crypt*

Comment: Even if it's unsalted, $1$ is still not just bare MD5 -- it's [md5crypt](https://pthree.org/2015/08/07/md5crypt-explained/), which involves 1000 rounds of MD5 with some other seasonings added.

Comment: The second hash is just md5('password').  `echo -n 'password' | md5sum` produces `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`